# How to send HTML message using PHP?

Tags: php, email, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to send the message as HTML, but it's arrived as XML Escape!!

**Example in screenshot:**

[image]

second problem is, if i typing the subject in "Arabic language" it's encoded in ANSI.

but if i test to send the same message via Gmail the subject be fine, but the content arrived as XML Escape!!

**PHP CODE:**

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "email@gmail.com"; 
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " " . "\n\n";
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers = "From: Brand Name <info@my-dmoain.me>" . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f info@my-dmoain.me");
    echo "Thanks";
}
?>
```

I cant figure out what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest always use a Mail Library for sending mails via PHP, then most of your problems will go away ;) For example https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer is a good library

Comment: @Fabian N. Thank you very mcuh, Thank you, just like what you said all of the problems i had is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add concat shorthand `.=` to this line:

```
 $headers = "From: Ali Najm <ali-najm@iraqnaa.me>" . "\r\n";
```

You're reassigning $headers var.

[Sending nice html with php](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Comment: Thanks, the message content problem is solved, do you know if there is any idea to fix subject problem!!

Comment: please can you edit your comment and change my email and name to somthing like this: email@domain.com , Example Name thanks